# Selenium By.linkText issues

Tags: selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, automation

So i am automating few tests for this one page, and using method "linkText" for finding element does not work even though it is clearly there,selector is written properly,element is visibile etc. Using its xpath does work however.

Any similiar experiences , ideas what may be the cause?

[Update]

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up/login"));


<li class="n15-menu-arrow pull-right"><a href="/sales/category/3/Kids-sales">Sign up/login</a>
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with your code and html code? we can not help you until then.

Comment: I forgot to ask, what exception / error messages did you get from your code?

Comment: What is the XPath that works?

Comment: is the element inside an iframe that you must switchTo() first?

Comment: XPath: "//a[.='Sign up/login']"

Comment: @YuZhang org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException                                          no iframe

Comment: Have you tried with `WebDriverWait`...??

Comment: @YuZhang Wowo the problem was simple. I checked the DOM and it turned that the innerText is "SIGN UP/LOGIN" and innerHTML is  "Sign up/login". Works with the innerText. Ths for ideas guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, can you please try `partialLinkText`?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("login"));
```

or

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sign"));
```

If you locate a wrong element, that means in your HTML there are other elements happen to share this partial link text in their attributes, in that case, I recommend using **Css Selector**.